# Testing if puppet apply is finished: xxx_controller.pp

Tags: puppet, openstack

I install the openstack one key:

```
packstack --allinone
```

But get stuck in here:

`Testing if puppet apply is finished: 103.xxx_controller.pp`

[image]

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It takes 30 minutes or more depending upon ram and cpu of machine on which you are installing packstack/devstack. Let it finish and wait it out. Error or success message will appear after it finishes.